# Cannot edit vertex after join

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Also cant edit even though I've been editing in the same object. I needed to redo a torso and separated the arms and head but now that I have brought them back I cannot edit the existing meshes, only the torso I've been working on. Edges and faces are selectable...but will not move, it's like the vertex data is gone.

I've had this happen when I join objects as well, actually never had a successful join with a mesh I couldn't edit anymore, hence the headline. But now I stayed only in edit mode (same object) and the existing mesh is doing the same thing. You can see in the photo how there are no vertex points to even select

[image: existing meshes no longer editable yet same object]

I've only had this happen since 2.83 and 2.9 (current). Removing modifiers, applying modifiers same result (obviously I am trying to reapply mirror here), overlay and viewport data unchanged, xray makes no difference, even tried dumb stuff, tried removing dupe verts, duping mesh, etc, nothing gets the mesh back...

Answer (score 0):

I closed and reopened then tried unhiding again because I was running out of ideas. And it worked. No idea why, and can't duplicate it the problem either so I have no explanation.